# What's a good source of information about how the structure of english sentences has evolved over time?

Tags: english, reference-request, language-change, phrase-structure

There is a lot of information about the evolution of English vocabulary since Anglo-Saxon times, but I am looking for examples of how English sentence construction has changed over time.

Comment: I vote to leave this question open.

Comment: This is indeed broad but a good question on the other hand. I vote to leave this question open.

Answer (score 1):

Ian Roberts's 1993 book *Verbs and Diachronic Syntax* has a good amount of (comparative) information on the history of English (and French) sentential structure. It's couched in late-GB terms, but I don't remember it being too over-the-top theory-heavy. I used it in a Historical Syntax class and remember liking it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a recent [textbook by Bettelou Los](https://edinburghuniversitypress.com/book-a-historical-syntax-of-english.html) which deals with exactly this topic. Not too pricey, either, by academic book standards.